# Transpose of Query Result

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

We have a requirement where we need to transpose the query results .The query result  is something like below.

```
Accnt   Country Weight
Acct1   US  55
Acct1   GB  45
Acct2   GB  35
Acct2   US  65
```

The output need to be transposed like below.

```
    Acct1   Acct2
US  55  65
GB  45  35
```

I have tied declare block ,but this query will be used in Dot net framework where they cant use declare block.So request the experts let me know possible ways to do this in single query ,both initial and the transpose.The accounts will be dynamic .

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: Search for PIVOT

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT`

```
select *
from (select Accnt,country,weight from test)
pivot (max(weight) for Accnt IN ('Acct1','Acct2'));

COUNTRY 'Acct1' 'Acct2'
US  55  65
GB  45  35
```

Comment: Thanks for your Query.How would we modify the query when the Accnt field is dynamic menaing , i will not know how mwany accounts will ther be

Comment: I dont know a direct way in PIVOT but by using PL/SQL you can achieve this. http://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/

Answer (score 1):

PIVOT is what you need, but there's also another option.

```
select  Country,
        max(case when Accnt = 'Acct1' then Weight end) Acct1,
        max(case when Accnt = 'Acct2' then Weight end) Acct2
from    test
group   by Country;
```

Comment: Thanks.How would we query when the Accnt field is dynamic.When Accnt are constant we can use the query you suggested.

Comment: @Ram, In such a case I'd suggest creating a procedure that creates and populates a temporary table and returns it's name. Another option is to extract the table in the long form (as it is) and making it wide (as you need) using some client-side formatting tools. Whatever solution you choose, please share it here. Thanks